# Possible to automate ios bundling process?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bundle

Everytim before trying to achive, I have to run the following command in terminal

> react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios

Is there by any chance I can automate it like says it gets rebundle on command `react-native run-ios`?

Not sure if it's related but I found the following code in my `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  "test": "jest",
  "android-linux": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android"
},
```

Wondering if the above `android-linux` will be triggered automatically when we run `react-native run-android`?

Also, for iOS, I understand the need to bundle it and we change the AppDelegate.m to point to main bundle as below

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

But I don't understand how Android will point the bundle created from scripts, all this time we only run command `./gradlew assembleRelease` to generate the APK

Comment: Check whether you have "Bundle React Native code and images" in Build Phases of your project, You will have a script "react-native-xcode.sh" this will automatically bundle the things when you archive. Don't you have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your script you can run `yarn android-linux` for android.

For iOS, add `react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios`

to `package.json` > `scripts`, like:

`"iOS-build": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios"`

then you can run `yarn iOS-build`

Comment: Thanks anhtu. When we run command `yarn android-linux`, it will generate the bundle but I'm wondering if I need to change anything to gradle so that the released APK will point to the generated bundle?

Comment: How did you get release apk?. I'm sorry that I don't know about android.

Comment: Anyway you can append cmd to scripts with `&&` as `"android-linux"` line  so they will execute synchronously